# Layer name is not a string

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to make a supervised classification program in GEE. But it gives me the error: Layer name is not a string: ee.Classifier

```
// Define a region in which to generate a sample of the input.
var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-71, -1.5, -67, 2.2);

// Display the sample region.
Map.setCenter(-68.50, 0.43, 7);

//select sentinel image
var img = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20170813T145731_20170813T145912_T19NEA');

//merging samples
var amostra = clareira.merge(agua).merge(mata).merge(nuvem);
//Map.addLayer(amostra);

//selecting bands
var bandas = ['B4','B3','B2'];

//creating training set
var training = img.select(bandas).sampleRegions({
  collection:amostra,
  properties:['class'],
  scale:10
});

//selecting classification algorithm
var classificacao = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty:['class'],
  inputProperties:bandas});

var result = img.select(bandas).classify(classificacao);

//Map.addLayer(img, {bands:'B4,B3,B2'});
Map.addLayer(result, {min: 0, max:3, palette:['magenta', 'blue', 'green', 'white']},classificacao);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the error, the layer name (the third argument in Map.addLayer) should be a string. change your last line to this:

```
Map.addLayer(result, {min: 0, max:3, palette:['magenta', 'blue', 'green', 'white']},'classificacao');
```